# How to setup healthcheck in Dockerfile on AWS ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

AWS ECS never checks health state although I've added healthcheck command in dockerfile.

I didn't put any additional setting on ECS healthchecker options, knowing it will override the original docker healthcheck command.

Any ideas?

Comment: While ECS will override the healthchecks in the Dockerfile I am not sure the native Dockerfile healthchecks will flow into ECS. Is there any reason why you do not want to use the ECS task definition helathcheck container(s) configurations?

Comment: @mreferre No. Actually I just want to use DockerFile for studying... without infra(aws). After read this reference https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1443#issuecomment-882124085, I decided to just use AWS. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I have investigated this today and it seems ECS does not support using `HEALTHCHECK` defined in the `Dockerfile`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_healthcheck
explicitly says

```
The Amazon ECS container agent only monitors and reports on the health checks that are specified in the task definition. Amazon ECS doesn't monitor Docker health checks that are embedded in a container image but aren't specified in the container definition.
```

So you need to add the `healthcheck` option to the task definition for ECS to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a container `healthcheck` via the container in `containerDefinitions` in your taskDefintion

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_healthcheck